# Can not modify return value Dictionary <string, Point> because it is not a variable

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm getting this error in the title, and here is the problem code:

```
Dictionary<string, Point> dicPoint = new Dictionary<string, Point>();
dicPoint.Add("point1", new Point());
dicPoint["point1"].X++;
```

At the time of incrementing X, it gives error. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: @HastaTamang: While that's true, this is a compile-time error that's unrelated to the NullReferenceException the OP would currently receive if it *did* compile.

Comment: C# It's very annoying in this factor.

Comment: Would you rather it didn't give you a compile-time error, but let you modify the copy of a value, without modifying what's in the dictionary? If you want reference type behaviour, use a reference type. I don't see anything wrong with what C# is doing here.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. I am a beginner in C# and for me this is complicated, I have to dig deeper ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the `Point` type you're using is a struct. Therefore fetching `dicPoint["point1"]` will create a *copy* of the value. Changing that would not change what's in the dictionary. Instead, you'll need to fetch the value, modify it, then replace the entry in the dictionary:

```
var point = dicPoint["point1"];
point.X++;
dicPoint["point1"] = point;
```